# Best practice to display components based on conditions in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a module that has four different components. 
I would like to display the components based on an id variable. At the moment, I am displaying them with ngIf, which doesn't seem to be the best practice for me. 
Is there any best practice to display components conditionally?

Current Implementation:

```
<component-one *ngif="id===1"></component-one>
<component-two *ngif="id===2"></component-two>
<component-three *ngif="id===3"></component-three>
<component-four *ngif="id===4"></component-four>
```

Comment: You could use *ngSwitch

Answer (score 1):

Try ngSwitch which is cleaner if you have more than 2 if conditions

```
 <div [ngSwitch]="id">
       <component-one *ngSwitchCase="1"></component-one>
      <component-two *ngSwitchCase="2"></component-two>
       <h1 *ngSwitchDefault>default</h1>    
     </div>
```